# Riddle in an epitaph

Tags: riddle

A man was walking through a graveyard and saw the following words written on his father's tombstone:

- be
- I
- me
- was
- will
- you

What was the father's epitaph? You will need to know the correct order of the words, and the number of times that each word occurs.

Comment: Too open-ended. I know you said somewhere in the comments that it is hard to restrict answers to a manageable answer set, but this is the fault of the riddle itself then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one seems to be a bit more on the open-ended side, but here's my go:

> I was you
>  You will be me
>      Explanation:
> I (dead guy) was you (the person reading it -- who is *alive*)
>  ... That is to say, the person who was once alive is now dead.
>      You (person reading -- alive) will be me (dead -- eventually)
>  ... Which is to say, the person who is currently alive will at some time in the future be dead.

Comment: Well played, sir!

Comment: Or "You, I was.  Me, you will be. - Yoda"

Answer (score 5):

> I was me
>
> you will be you

It seems rather free form.  I don't know how to judge if it is the right answer.

This means that your Dad whoever he was was himself and lived his own life.  You (whoever you are reading this) should be who you are and live your own life as well.

In other words, "be yourself."

Comment: It is an epitaph.

Comment: I know you have a specific idea in mind but I think you may want to restict the potential answers more.  As it is there are probably alot of valid answers.  You don't even specifiy whether those are he only words in the epitaph.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to think of ways to be more specific but it's hard to do that without giving away the answer..

Answer (score 4):

I was me. Will you be?

The father made decisions best for himself. He wants those living to make their own choices in life and not simply repeat his